# Difference between add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' ) and add_theme_support( 'custom-header')

Tags: wordpress-theming

Where `add_theme_support( 'custom-header')` is used as most of the themes shows `add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' )`. Can someone clarify how both works? Developer documentation is not providing exact details were to use those.